# give a root privilege to a python GUI application to run a command in ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, user-interface, ubuntu, pyqt

Now, i have a python GUI app which need to run a command with sudo privilege like this below:

```
import commands
iStat, askpassPath = commands.getstatusoutput("which ssh-askpass")
cmd = "export SUDO_ASKPASS=%s;sudo -A mkdir -p /usr/lib/test"%(askpassPath)
commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)
```

[image]

This works fine if ssh-askpass has been installed on ubuntu.But it seems some ubuntu systems don't install it by default while i can't install it for them.

So, I need to know if there is another way for me to get a sudo privilege.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:The app should not be started with root privilege.It needs to get root privilege only when it is running.

Comment: It's very interesting question for me. I think you should use `gksu / gksudo` ([How can I run an application with a GUI as admin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164819/how-can-i-run-an-application-with-a-gui-as-admin-from-a-non-admin-user-session)) as the frontend application to get root privileges before you start the application. After this you should execute a root-command and then you should down the privileges. If the application started without root-privileges you should inform user about it. This is how I see it. You can see similar behavior in *wireshark* application.

Comment: @first.This solution is not suitable for me, because our app is used for work, the user will not be able to run it with root privilege. Also, i can't give them a tooltip, because other functions don't need root privilege, it will cause bad user experience.So, what i can do is to get interim root privilege to do something when the command really needs root privilege.

Comment: `ssh-askpass` is just a program which shows dialog windows and write to stdout the password entered by user. I hope you can do some tool application which will do the job and specify it as an `SUDO_ASKPASS` program for `sudo`.

Comment: @first.It seems to make sense.Is it possible for me to write a tool app with Qt over ubuntu14.04 and ubuntu16.04.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're for "another way for me to get a sudo privilege". You can, and probably should, not run the application with elevated privileges.

An option I see is to install a helper binary and store it with a [SUID-bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid). You can then call this binary to have your operation performed.

If you do want to run with elevated privileges, you may want to have a look at [consolehelper](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/consolehelper8.html).  Even the [Qt wiki](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_get_applications_running_with_root_privileges) mentions that method.

To give a more complete answer, I'll try to lay out what steps you need to do. This is not meant as a comprehensive set of instructions. Please refer to the documentation.

Essentially, try

```
ln -s /usr/sbin/consolehelper /usr/bin/yourapp-root
```

Then configure PAM (e.g. /etc/pam.d/yourapp-root):

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth            include         config-util
account         include         config-util
session         include         config-util
```

And then /etc/security/console.apps/yourapp-root:

```
USER=root
PROGRAM=/usr/bin/yourapp
```

Comment: Thanks for help.Some people can get our app from our site which is "deb" format.So i can't do these for them.And installing app from ubuntu software center which will also pop up a dialog like the picture in my question.So i think it's feasible.